# how to save video to local store with the help of camera package

Tags: flutter, video, camera, video-capture

i am using the camera package into my project i am able to click and save image into my local gallery but i m not able to save video

```
onLongPress: () {
  setState(() {
           videoIcon = true;                                        
           cc.stopVideoRecording();                                        
           cc.initialize();                                     
           });
          },
 onTap: () {                                      
    if (videoIcon) {                                        
      setState(() {                                         
      cc.stopVideoRecording();                                        
      cc.initialize();                                         
      videoIcon = false;                                        
   });                                      
  }                                    });
```

Comment: With package library use for camera package? I suggest to explain your issue in more detail and the source code is not very clear.